# Problem with SRT file (index and empty line)

Tags: notepad++, srt

How can I change the following `.srt` file to look like the one at the end of the post?:

```
1

1

00:00:01,270  -->  00:00:04,520
<v Narrator>Now before diving into some NodeJS code,</v>
2

2

00:00:04,520  -->  00:00:06,700
let's do a high level overview
```

I want to change it into this (not duplicate index and remove empty line):

```
1
00:00:01,270  -->  00:00:04,520
<v Narrator>Now before diving into some NodeJS code,</v>

2
00:00:04,520  -->  00:00:06,700
let's do a high level overview
```

I think I can use Notepad++ but how?

Comment: Is there literally "//empty line"  written in that line or is there jut an empty line (ie with no content) And are there multiple consecutive empty lines, or is there just a single one?

Comment: //empty line: just a single one and no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumming `//empty line` don't exist as literal**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R?\d+\R+(\d+\R)\R*(.+\R.+(\R?))`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\R+         # any kind of linebreak
(           # group 1
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
)           # end group
\R*         # any kind of linebreak
(           # group 2
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    (\R?)       # group 3, any kind of linebreak, optional
)           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the digits
$2          # content of group 2, the text
$3          # content of group 3, optional linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]